# How to show tabs vertically in Chrome?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, browser-addons, browser-tabs

There's an addon for Firefox, which is the only reason to use Firefox for me: Tree Style Tabs. I've heard there was a build of Chrome with such function, but was unable to find it. How do I show tabs as a tree in Chrome? I'm using Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: I don't think such a thing is possible. Chrome's UI is virtually set in stone.

Comment: @DanielB Here's a screenshot of that build: http://www.sotovik.ru/images/news2/04.10.2010/omnibox-tabs-chrome-1.jpeg

Comment: @DanielB It's not an addon, it's just a hardcoded function, which was tested by Chrome guys, but never got into production.

Comment: Apparently, this feature [has been removed](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=83008). Considering this was roughly a gazillion versions ago, re-applying the changes will be next to impossible.

Comment: @DanielB I've made a bug report. Hopefully guys will find some time for it. http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=344870

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the same functionality than [Tree Style Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tree-style-tab/) (for Firefox), you can try the ported extension(s) for Chrome:

- [Sidewise Tree Style Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sidewise-tree-style-tabs/biiammgklaefagjclmnlialkmaemifgo?hl=en)
- [Tree Style Tabs (Beta)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tree-style-tabs-beta/ffididlaalcoegfcalmeldjfnihmoech)

It won't remove the tabs on top though.